# One CCAction to few sprites - need to properly remove them all

Tags: ios, memory-management, cocos2d-iphone

I add one sprite per body and run animation, but when I try to remove this sprite after reloading scene(calling afterLoadProcessing once again) - removes the only first with animation. I'm new to iOS & Cococs2D programming, please help me with advice.

Here is my code:

```
-(void)afterLoadProcessing:(b2dJson*)json
{
    [super afterLoadProcessing:json];

    [self removeChild:enemysprite cleanup:YES];

    [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"player_enemy.plist"];
    CCSpriteBatchNode *spriteSheet = [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:@"player_enemy.png"];
    [self addChild:spriteSheet];

NSMutableArray *enemyGusenitsaAnimFrames = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (int i = 31; i <=36; ++i) {
        [enemyGusenitsaAnimFrames addObject:
         [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:
          [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.png",i]]];
    }
    CCAnimation *gusenitsaMovAnim = [CCAnimation animationWithSpriteFrames:enemyGusenitsaAnimFrames delay:0.1f];
    _enemyGusenitsaMovement = [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:
                                    [CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:gusenitsaMovAnim]];
    _enemyGusenitsaMovement.tag = 109;

std::vector<b2Body*> enemySprites;
    json->getBodiesByName("enemy", enemySprites);
    for (int i = 0; i < enemySprites.size(); i++) {
        b2Body *bod = enemySprites[i];
        enemysprite = [[CCSprite alloc] init];

        [enemysprite stopAllActions];
        enemysprite.scale = 0.04;
        [self addChild:enemysprite z:50];
        bod->SetUserData(enemysprite);
        [[enemysprite runAction:[_enemyGusenitsaMovement copy]] autorelease];
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of use `[self removeChild:enemysprite cleanup:YES];`, you can remove all children

```
 [self removeAllChildrenWithCleanup:YES];
```

Or loop all bodies and remove it :

```
for (int i = 0; i < enemySprites.size(); i++) {
    b2Body *bod = enemySprites[i];
    CCSprite *sprite = (CCSprite *)bod->GetUserData();
    [self removeChild:sprite];
}
```

Comment: You're welcome! Please, if my answer is the right one, mark it as correct, to help other users that come at this topic with same problem.